# Reactjs update status

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

Please see my code below, I dont know how to implement of how to update the selected student status, I can get the Id and the status of what i clicked.

```
export const UPDATESTATUS = gql`
mutation UpdateStatus($status: String!, $id: String!) {
  updateStatus(status: $status, id: $id) {
    id
    status
  }
}
```

`

//

```
import {UPDATESTATUS} from '../utils/student.gql'
....

  const handleUpdateStatus = () => {
    console.log("id: ", student.id, "status", student.status) // ID and status of student selected
    setOpenAlert({
      open: true,
      success: true,
    })
    setOpen(false)
    useQuery (UPDATESTATUS, {
    variables: { id: student.id, status: student.status},
    update(cache, result){
       console.log(result)
    }
    })
  }
```

the error says

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of
> the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Answer (score 0):

It is a breaking the [React hooks rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions) to use them in the callbacks  (*don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions*).

In your case you use Apollo's **useQuery** hook in the **handleUpdateStatus** function, so you got an error.

In the Apollo, for GraphQL mutations, it is better to use [**useMutation**](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2/data/mutations/). It's pretty straightforward.